# Apache catch HOSTNAME and all Sub Domains

Tags: apache, vhosts

Firstly, i'm not looking to catch all subdomains, i know how to do this. But for some reason i cant seem to resolve just the hostname.

So, i can resolve:

http://stackoverflow-is-great.example.com

but for some reason i cant resolve the domain when i do:

http://example.com/

i'm not keen to redirect the user to www. if they hit the hostname all i want is a vhost that can handle both (or a way to do this)

this is simple stuff, but i just cant seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

stupid me, i had the DNS settings setuo incorrectly.

turns out if you dont have an @ record the hostname wont resolve. *slaps head*